# search with in_array in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

My English issnt so good sorry for that.

i have a array:

```
Array ( [name] => Array 
                      ( 
                      [0] => Sorry the name is missing! 
                      [1] => Sorry the name is to short! 
                      ) 
)
```

Now I want to test with in_array for eg "name".

```
if (in_array("name", $false["name"])) {
echo "the array keys";
}
```

but it dsnt work. could annybody help me please? thanks a lot.

Comment: When you test for *name*, what should be the outcome of the test? That *name* is an array or a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try array_key_exists(): [link](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists)

```
if(array_key_exists('name', $false['name'])) {
    echo $false['name'][0]; // or [1] .. or whatever you want to echo
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`in_array()` does not work with multi-dimensional arrays, so it is not possible to use `in_array()` here. When you are searching "name" in `in_array()` it searches in the first array and finds a key of the array named "name".

Better to use [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function. An example is given below: (remember it is only a suggestion. code may vary)

```
if(array_key_exists('name', $false['name'])) {
    echo $false['name'][0]; // or [1] .. or whatever you want to echo
}
//$false['name'] array contains your searched data in different keys; 0,1,2,....
```

You can use `foreach()` to loop the first array then search using `in_array()` but that will not be a good method because it will take more time to find.
Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to walk through the array first, then check it

```
function in_multiarray($str, $array)
{
    $exists = false;

    if (is_array($array)) {
       foreach ($array as $arr):
           $exists = in_multiarray($str, $arr);
       endforeach;
    } else {
        echo $array . ' = ' . $str . "\n";
        if (strpos($array, $str) !== false) $exists = true;
    }

    return $exists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) looks for the exact value. So you would need to specify `"Sorry the name is missing!"` instead of just `"name"`.

For example:

```
if (in_array("Sorry the name is missing!", $false["name"])) {
    echo "the array keys";
}
```

Where:

```
$false = array( 'name' => array( 
    0 => 'Sorry the name is missing!',
    1 => 'Sorry the name is to short!'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[If you are searching for array key **name** in your main array:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
$arr = array( "name" => array( 
                      "0" => "Sorry the name is missing!", 
                      "1" => "Sorry the name is to short!" 
               )); 

if(array_key_exists('name', $arr)) {
    print_r( $arr['name'] );
} else {
    echo "array key not found";
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/oWaNhC8m)

It will not find **name** if you will search in **$arr['name']** because it contains only **0** and **1** array keys at this level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use in_array
you just need to put the second parameter as the array you have defined
example

```
if(in_array('name',$false){
//do your stuff
print_r($false['name']); //this will print the array of name inclusive of [0] and [1]
}
```

There are more example given in the [in_array php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). please check it out.